# Represent regular languages and automata having more than 26 symbols in their alphabet

Tags: automata, regular-language, math-software, gap

I'm working on regular languages and automata with arbitrary numbers of symbols for their alphabet (maybe more than 26.) So I'm showing the alphabet symbols by $a1, a2, ..., an$.
For example a regular expression is generated in GAP like this: $"@Ua3Ua3a1Ua1Ua3a2Ua2"$ where $@$ means epsilon and $U$ means union.
When I write the code depicted below, the generated automaton assumes the alphabet includes $a$ and numbers $1$ to $n$. (In this case $n=3$).

After loading the [Automata package](https://gap-packages.github.io/automata/) with `LoadPackage("automata");`, we have:

```
gap> w := "@Ua3Ua3a1Ua1Ua3a2Ua2";;
gap> r := RationalExpression(w);;
gap> Display(RatExpToAut(r));
   |  1  2  3  4  5  6
-----------------------
 1 |  2  3  3  2  3  3
 2 |  2  3  3  2  3  3
 3 |  5  3  3  3  3  3
 a |  3  3  3  3  4  1

Initial state:    [ 6 ]
Accepting states: [ 2, 5, 6 ]
```

How can I specify the alphabet in order to make it understand that for example $a1$ is a single symbol?
If it's not possible in GAP, I appreciate alternative solutions using other softwares or programming languages.

Comment: The easiest solution is to remplace $a1$ by $a$, $a2$ by $b$ etc.

Comment: @thibo Yeah. But I said the number of symbols is arbitrary. In this case, it is practical. But for the alphabets having more than 26 symbols, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but could you use one letter, say z, as an end-of-symbol punctuation mark, so that the first 25 symbols would be az, bz, ..., yz, and then the next 625 symbols would be aaz, abz, acz, ... baz, bbz... yyz, and so on? Note that this doesn't require GAP to think about the clusters of symbols; to GAP the symbols are still the single letters a through z.

Comment: @MJD I don't know. The main question is that when I use the function "RatExpToAut", it will identify the alphabet automatically. Is there a way to customize the alphabet and specify it?

Comment: According to the manual `RationalExpression` allows for an extra parameter that gives an alphabet. You should be able to use other symbols than the 26 lower case letters for this.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. I tried it now. But it shows this error: "Error, The arguments to RationalExpression must be a string." So I can't pass the list ["a1", "a2", "a3"] for the alphabet.

Comment: You might have to use single symbols, but should be able to go beyond the 26 characters.

Comment: @ahulpke Yeah, and how?

Comment: It seems like it must be possible (see e.g. example for [AlphabetOfRatExpAsList](https://gap-packages.github.io/automata/doc/chap3.html#X84B9922B7C006158)). For a specific GAP package, it may be better to write to package authors (please include the link to this question while emailing them).

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thanks. I think this is the best thing I can do. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some issue either in the 'automata' package since RationalExpression does not behave as expected when considering large alphabets... Please consider putting an issue in https://github.com/gap-packages/automata

Independently of the way the issue will be fixed, it may be advisable to construct your regular expressions at a lower level, as in the following example

```
gap> @ := RatExpOnnLetters(30,[],[]);
@
gap> a1 := RatExpOnnLetters(30,[],[1]);
a1
gap> a5 := RatExpOnnLetters(30,[],[5]);
a5
gap> a25 := RatExpOnnLetters(30,[],[25]);
a25
gap> r := UnionRatExp(@,a1);
@Ua1
gap> r := UnionRatExp(r,StarRatExp(UnionRatExp(a5,ProductRatExp(a1,a25))));
@Ua1U(a5Ua1a25)*
gap> nfa := RatExpToNDAut(r);
< non deterministic automaton on 30 letters with 5 states >
```